# What happens to the output stream when I'm sending a file from a servlet to a browser?

Tags: java, servlets, download

I have an application which is used by users to download  some files that are retrived unfortunately via a webservice.The webservice provide the content of the files inside the payload :(

So i might have a lot of documents simultaneously in the memory of the webapp thing that leads to out of memory.

The question is : when the user press on the webage download I start writing on the outputstream...but the user receives a popup with "save" or "cancel".
What happens with the document until he press save ?
What if he press cancel ?

The output stream is blocked on write until the user press save ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the outputstream is not locked, it's buffered and it's sent to the client when your servlet container thinks it's the right time (or when you force sending with a flush() call on it).

Depending on your server infrastructure (if you have or not a reverse proxy in front of your web server) your request may fail or not, but usually you don't have to care about this.

And regarding the memory issue, you should probably call the web and either write directly as you read from it to the request output stream or you should write this to a file and then write this file in chunks to the response to avoid using too much memory and bringing the server down due to out of memory errors.

Comment: Thanks ...it would be nice to be able to read from an inputstream and to write directly on the outputstream but the content of the file that is downlaoded comes as string in the payload of a soap message...so there i have getContent only which is a big .very big string...i have to live with that for now cause it is not up to me.

Comment: When user press download...in the code from server i start to write in the outputstream ,the client get the downlaod popup with save or cancel..IN this moment where is the file ? ... :)

Comment: The browser is usually downloading the file at this point, but this is implementation dependent. They have already started receiving the answer from your servlet, so they are downloading the file. You can see this happening by downloading an executable file from Google Chrome, sometimes it downloads the file before you even say yes.

Comment: Ahha...so even if i do not press save i might download the file ? Strange :)

Comment: Yes, the browsers are just making life easier for you, instead of blocking and not downloading they just hope for the best (you're going to accept the download) and move on. Once you say no they usually cancel the request and delete the file.